# Migrating data from one table to other in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

i need to migrate data from one table to other.

```
CREATE TABLE asses (
  id uuid,
  toid text,
  name text,
  fbid text,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) WITH
coments = '';
CREATE TABLE basses (
  id text,
  canid uuid,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) WITH
comment= '';
```

I need to move data from asses to basses.
Also data from coulmns name and fbid should go to id and data from id should go to canid.

I know joins do not work here.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 3):

The following copy commands should do the trick:

```
COPY asses (name, id) TO 'file1.csv';
COPY asses (fbid, id) TO 'file2.csv';

COPY basses (id, canid) FROM 'file1.csv';
COPY basses (id, canid) FROM 'file2.csv';
```

You can then delete all rows from the original table:

```
TRUNCATE asses;
```

Hope this helps.